# Chrome, Firefox, Wordpress anchor tags randomly appearing

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox

I am creating a Wordpress theme. In the IDE there are no anchor tags in the footer element. However, when loaded in Chrome and Firefox anchor tags appear throughout the footer.
Code as in IDE(Netbeans)

```
<footer class='bootstrap-classes'>
    <p>The Client's Address</p>
</footer>
```

Code as in Chrome/Firefox

```
<a href="#">
    <footer class='bootstrap-classes'>
        <a href="#"><p>The Client's Address</p></a>
    </footer>
</a>
```

Also - my javascript files, loaded after the footer, are encased in anchor tags.

Steps taken:

I've scanned my computer for any malware/adware - nothing (AVG)

Plugins Used:
Advanced Custom Fields https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/
Scripts:
bootstrap js cdn
jQuery Google API 2.2.0
wp-embed js
bootstrap css cdn
wp-emoji-release js
respond js (If IE)

Comment: show how you write that output in screen. you are wrapping in somewhere you didn't notice

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I replied with my own answer. "Syntax mistake, img tag with an anchor parent was left unclosed.". Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, but we couldn't reproduce that issue or solve your problem since you are not attach the correct code. Try to attach a working example next time. With that, in syntax errors or typographycal you solve the problem before ask here, so it's better for you and for all.

Comment: This should be closed as typographycal error :)

Comment: My apologies, the client does not want any segments of its code posted. However, next time I will do my best to reproduce the code in such a way not to violate my contract.

Comment: Ok, I understand, the same case here, but I recommend to reproduce the problem even not the exact same code, because is clearful. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Syntax mistake, img tag with an anchor parent was left unclosed.